# How do I create a Compute Engine instance with no external IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I've been following a guide to create and Compute Engine instance with Cloud NAT.

After following up to Step 5 to create a Compute Engine instance with the guide found [here](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gce-example), I found that I could SSH into my instance and reach the internet, which is not what I'd expect.

In the same step, there's a link that leads to troubleshooting this problem found [here](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/troubleshooting#internet-wo-nat). The top listed issue is that the instance has an external IP address, despite the instructions explicitly (Step 2) saying to set that option to "None."

I went back to the Compute Engine UI for creating a new instance to triple check that this option was set to "None" [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvEI.png). After clicking "Done" and clicking "Create" on the instance, the UI shows what I would expect [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUHpx.png) with an external IP of None. Yet, after finishing the creation process, I get something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo4uH.png) which has a specified external IP address anyway.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Am I missing a step in specifying external IP address?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I tried this on a new project and everything worked as expected. Got a VM with no external IP address and after adding firewall ingress rule for SSH manually I got into it from the console but it had no access to internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems something weird is happening to project. Could you please try to create a VM with the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) instead of the console and make sure you [remove the accessConfigs member](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign) completely for creating a VM without external IP.

In addition, on inspecting your shared screenshot it seems you are using the custom VPC, could you please try to [create VM with default VPC and set-up NAT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y47yGMY2-UU&t=756s)  with it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried both creating the instance through gcloud and explicity setting no external IP: `gcloud compute instances create {name} --network-interface=no-address` as well as creating an instance normally and deleting access configs `gcloud compute instances delete-access-config {name}`.

Both get the job done. Appreciate the help!